# module 'collections' has no attribute 'MutableMapping' while trying to run `Jupyter-lab` command on a virtual env [conda]

Tags: python, collections, conda, virtual, jupyter-lab

I uninstalled the virtual env and did a fresh install, but still the same error occurs, while Jupyter-notebook, works fine.

[image]

*I created the virtual env from a .yml file
[image]

Comment: Your conda environment does not specify jupyterlab. Your screenshot confirms that you are using JupyterLab installed on Python 3.10 (completely independent of conda installation). The obvious question is what is the version of JupyterLab in the Python 3.10 environment and whether it is up to date (my guess is it is outdated hence the compatibility issue) and whether you really intended to use it (rather than install a copy in the conda env).

Comment: @krassowski you are right, when I did a fresh install I forgot to check for jupyter-lab, I did not check for it as it was auto-completing when I pressed tab key so though it was pre installed, but nonetheless, thank you, I just add to install jupyter-lab and ran into another error, which from google found out that I had to downgrade the Jupiter-client by 1 version, it is now working as expected